# Find Multiple Flagged String within String Python

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I have multiple flagged strings:

```
FLGSTdata1FLGEN
FLGSTdata2FLGEN
...
```

where `FLGST` is start flag and `FLGEN` is end flag.

I combine those strings and add some garbage data, so it looks like this:

```
garbagegarbageFLGSTdata1FLGENFLGSTdata2FLGENgarbagegarbageFLGSTdata3FLGEN...
```

I need to get each of flagged strings from the combined strings.

Here is what I've done using `re`:

```
>>> pattern = r'5354([A-Za-z0-9_]*)454E' #FLGST = 5354 and FLGEN = 454E
>>> data = re.findall(pattern,stringWithGarbage)
>>> print data[0]
data1FLGENFLGSTdata2FLGENgarbagegarbageFLGSTdata3
```

It returns all data except the `FLGST` of data1 and `FLGEN` of data last.

So, **how do you get each of flagged string from stringWithGarbage**?

The appropriate return would be:

```
[data1, data2, data3, ...]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Use a Regex to Filter Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284789/python-use-a-regex-to-filter-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using positive look behind and positive look ahead

```
strg = "garbagegarbageFLGSTdata1FLGENFLGSTdata2FLGENgarbagegarbageFLGSTdata3FLGEN"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=FLGST)(\S*?)(?=FLGEN)')
re.findall(pattern, strg)
```

Output

```
['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
```